# Characterization of projections in a C$^{*}$-‎algebra‎

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

please give me a hand.

let ‎‎$ a‎ ‎\in A ‎‎‎‎$ ‎be  a‎‎ ‎normal ‎element ‎of‎ the C$ ^{*}$- ‎algebra‎‎  ‎‎‎‎$ ‎A‎$‎.

> a)‎ ‎show ‎that‎ ‎$ ‎\sigma ( a‎ )‎ =‎ ‎\{ 0‎ ,‎ 1‎ ‎\} ‎‎$‎ ‎if ‎only ‎if  ‎‎$‎a ‎$ ‎is a ‎projection (‎‎‎$ a‎^{2} =‎ a‎ =‎ ‎a‎^{*}$)‎.
>
> b) ‎if ‎‎$a$ ‎is ‎hermitian ($a =‎a‎^{*}$) ‎and‎‎ ‎$  a‎^{3} =‎ ‎a‎^{2}$‎, ‎then ‎‎$‎a$  ‎is  ‎projection.

Comment: Are you working on a $*$-algebra, and not a C$^*$-algebra?

Comment: excuse me, it is  C∗-algebra

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is a projection, then $a^2-a=0$. That is $p(a)=0$, where $p$ is the polynomial $p(t)=t^2-t$. By the Spectral Mapping Theorem, $$\{0\}=\sigma(p(a))=p(\sigma(a)).$$ Then $\lambda^2-\lambda=0$ for all $\lambda\in\sigma(a)$. This shows that $\sigma(a)\subset\{0,1\}$. The equality does not necessarily hold: for instance $\sigma(0)=\{0\}$, and $\sigma(I)=\{1\}$.

If $\sigma(a)=\{0,1\}$, one can consider the abelian C$^*$-subalgebra $A_0$ generated by $a$. We have $$\{0,1\}=\sigma(a)=\{\omega(a):\ \omega\in\Sigma(A_0)\},$$ so $\omega(a)=1$ for every nonzero character. But then $\omega(a^*)=\overline{\omega(a)}=1$, so $\omega(a^*-a)=0$ for all characters. Similarly, $\omega(a^2-a)=0$ for all characters. Then $a^*=a=a^2$.

For part b), you have $0=a^3-a^2=0$. Then every $\lambda\in\sigma(a)$ satisfies $0=\lambda^3-\lambda^2=\lambda^2(\lambda-1)$. It follows that $\sigma(a)\subset\{0,1\}$ and so $a$ is projection by part a).